# cannot open file 'wxbase32u.lib' in CMake project with wxWidgets in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, cmake, wxwidgets

Ok that title might sound confusing.

Basically, I want to build my wxWidgets app with CMake instructions and *not* a **.sln** solution. So I created a visual studio **CMake Project**.

I have the following `.h` and `.cpp` files:

```
App.h
App.cpp
Window.h
Window.cpp
```

My `App.h` and `App.cpp` look like this:

**App.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "wx/wx.h"
 
class App : public wxApp
{
public:
    bool OnInit();
};
```

**App.cpp**

```
#include "App.h"
#include "Window.h"

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(App);

bool App::OnInit()
{
    MainWindow* window = new Window("GUI Title");
    window->Center();
    window->Show();

    return true;
}
```

My CMakeLists file ***contains*** the following:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_executable (SortingsVisualizer "App.h" "App.cpp" "Window.h" "Window.cpp")
add_compile_definitions(_UNICODE )
include_directories("D:\\C++libraries\\wxWidgets\\include\\msvc" "D:\\C++libraries\\wxWidgets\\include" )
link_directories("D:\\C++libraries\\wxWidgets\\lib\\vc_x64_lib")
```

I have the wxWidgets library installed at "*D:\C++libraries\wxWidgets*".
It works fine if I create a normal `.sln` solution and add the proper additional include/lib.

However, if I try run/build inside a **CMake Project** with the settings mentioned above, I get the following error:

> fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'wxbase32u.lib'

I checked and I do have the wxbase32u.lib file. What to do? ;(

Comment: Mixing 32 and 64 bit? Make sure your building for x64 and not Win32 since that is what your libs appear to be.

Comment: @drescherjm I am building for x64 Release

Comment: @zoinkers, look in the minimal sample folder. There is an example of CMake configuration file. Just make it look like that and it should work.

Comment: Thank you once again @Igor, I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69237426/finding-wxwidgets-on-cmake-with-cmake-prefix-path. Just copied the file and changed wxWidgets paths, n now it works!